# How can I join with a SQL view in a Hibernate query?

Tags: hibernate

I have created a SQL view that calculates a function of two table rows.  I want to use the view to limit the output of a hibernate query, but am not sure of the best way to do that.

The view encapsulates a stored function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(ax, ay, bx, by) AS ... ;

CREATE VIEW f_view AS
  SELECT a.id a_id, b.id b_id, f(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y) f FROM thing a, thing b;
```

Now I want to write a hibernate query similar to this SQL query:

```
SELECT Thing t1
INNER JOIN Thing t2 ...
INNER JOIN ...
INNER JOIN f_view v ON v.a_id = t1.id AND v.b_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = ? AND ... AND v.f < ?
```

Is it reasonable to use such a view in a hibernate query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only options here are:

1. Map your `f_view` as (most likely immutable) entity in Hibernate - you can then include it in your HQL query.
2. Write your query as SQL instead and map its results to your (managed or unmanaged) entities. [Chapter 18](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17428) of Hibernate reference documents all the possibilities here.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid that was the case.  I took option 2 before writing the question, and that works, but it's ugly.  I considered mapping the view but do not know what to do about an id for the view rows.

Comment: @kevin Is `a_id` / `b_id` combination unique within your view? If so, you can map it as a composite identifier. If not, you can throw `f`in there as well OR as long as `f_view` is both immutable and will never be retrieved directly by Hibernate (e.g. only used in joins) you can actually get away with duplicate IDs.

Comment: yes, it is unique.  I considered that approach too.  I will give it a try.